# Apache Solr DataImportHandler is not indexing data from database

Tags: drupal, solr, dataimporthandler

To import data from my database into Apache Solr, I am using the DataImportHandler. The integration of the DataImportHandler was successful, as well as the indexing seems so. But the "Total documents processed" is 0 and I can't find errors in the logs.

I use Apache Solr 3.5 with Drupal and a lot of items are already indexed. So, the schema.xml already has many fields. With the DataImportHandler I want to add some more content and therefore, some more fields. For testing, I have a test database with one column "id" (primary key) and another column "test_name" (text).

In other postings, I often saw similar issues, but nothing could help me, so I hope, you can.
I don't know whether there's something wrong with my field matching or if it's another problem.

This is my dataconfig.xml:

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" encoding="UTF-8"
                     url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test_db" 
                        user="user" password="password" batchSize="-1"/>
   <document>
     <entity pk="id" query="SELECT `id` AS ID,`test_name` AS TEST_NAME FROM `test`">
        <field column="ID" name="id" />
        <field column="TEST_NAME" name="test_name" />
     </entity>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

My schema.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<schema name="drupal-3.0-beta9-solr3" version="1.3">

  <types>

    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>

    <!-- boolean type: "true" or "false" -->
    <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <!--Binary data type. The data should be sent/retrieved in as Base64 encoded Strings -->
    <fieldtype name="binary" class="solr.BinaryField"/>


    <!-- numeric field types that can be sorted, but are not optimized for range queries -->
    <fieldType name="integer" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="float" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="double" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>

    <fieldType name="sint" class="solr.SortableIntField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="slong" class="solr.SortableLongField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="sfloat" class="solr.SortableFloatField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="sdouble" class="solr.SortableDoubleField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>

    <fieldType name="tint" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tfloat" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tlong" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tdouble" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>


    <fieldType name="date" class="solr.DateField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>

    <!-- A Trie based date field for faster date range queries and date faceting. -->
    <fieldType name="tdate" class="solr.TrieDateField" omitNorms="true" precisionStep="6" positionIncrementGap="0"/>


    <!-- A text field that only splits on whitespace for exact matching of words -->
    <fieldType name="text_ws" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>

        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="stopwords.txt"
                enablePositionIncrements="true"
                />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                protected="protwords.txt"
                generateWordParts="1"
                generateNumberParts="1"
                catenateWords="1"
                catenateNumbers="1"
                catenateAll="0"
                splitOnCaseChange="1"
                preserveOriginal="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.DictionaryCompoundWordTokenFilterFactory" dictionary="german-common-nouns.txt" minWordSize="5" minSubwordSize="2" maxSubwordSize="15" onlyLongestMatch="true"/>

        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="35" side="front"/>
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="stopwords.txt"
                enablePositionIncrements="true"
                />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <!-- An unstemmed text field - good if one does not know the language of the field -->
    <fieldType name="text_und" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                protected="protwords.txt"
                generateWordParts="1"
                generateNumberParts="1"
                catenateWords="1"
                catenateNumbers="1"
                catenateAll="0"
                splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="stopwords.txt"
                enablePositionIncrements="true"
                />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                protected="protwords.txt"
                generateWordParts="1"
                generateNumberParts="1"
                catenateWords="0"
                catenateNumbers="0"
                catenateAll="0"
                splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="edge_n2_kw_text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="100">
     <analyzer type="index">
       <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="25" />
     </analyzer>
     <analyzer type="query">
       <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
     </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
   <!--  Setup simple analysis for spell checking -->

   <fieldType name="textSpell" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
     <analyzer>
       <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
       <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
       <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="4" max="20" />
       <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
       <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
     </analyzer>
   </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="sortString" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>

        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <!-- The TrimFilter removes any leading or trailing whitespace -->
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />

      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <!-- A random sort type -->
    <fieldType name="rand" class="solr.RandomSortField" indexed="true" />

    <fieldtype name="ignored" stored="false" indexed="false" class="solr.StrField" />

    <fieldType name="point" class="solr.PointType" dimension="2" subFieldType="tdouble"/>

    <fieldType name="location" class="solr.LatLonType" subFieldType="tdouble"/>

    <fieldtype name="geohash" class="solr.GeoHashField"/>

 </types>


 <fields>

   <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
   <!-- entity_id is the numeric object ID, e.g. Node ID, File ID -->
   <field name="entity_id"  type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <!-- entity_type is 'node', 'file', 'user', or some other Drupal object type -->
   <field name="entity_type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
   <!-- bundle is a node type, or as appropriate for other entity types -->
   <field name="bundle" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="bundle_name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

   <field name="site" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="hash" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="url" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <!-- label is the default field for a human-readable string for this entity (e.g. the title of a node) -->
   <field name="label" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" termVectors="true" omitNorms="true"/>
   <!-- The string version of the title is used for sorting -->
   <copyField source="label" dest="sort_label"/>
   <!-- content is the default field for full text search - dump crap here -->
   <field name="content" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" termVectors="true"/>
   <field name="teaser" type="text" indexed="false" stored="true"/>

   <field name="path" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="path_alias" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" termVectors="true" omitNorms="true"/>

   <!-- new fields for grouping pdfs -->
   <field name="article_group" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" termVectors="true" multiValued="false"/>
   <field name="pdf_path" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <copyField source="path" dest="article_group"/>

   <field name="tid"  type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

   <field name="test_name" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" termVectors="true"/>

   <field name="taxonomy_names" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" termVectors="true" multiValued="true" omitNorms="true"/>
   <!-- Copy terms to a single field that contains all taxonomy term names -->
   <copyField source="tm_vid_*" dest="taxonomy_names"/>

   <!-- Here, default is used to create a "timestamp" field indicating
        when each document was indexed.-->
   <field name="timestamp" type="tdate" indexed="true" stored="true" default="NOW" multiValued="false"/>

    <!-- This field is used to build the spellchecker index -->
   <field name="spell" type="textSpell" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

  <!-- copyField commands copy one field to another at the time a document
        is added to the index.  It's used either to index the same field differently,
        or to add multiple fields to the same field for easier/faster searching.  -->
   <copyField source="label" dest="spell"/>
   <copyField source="content" dest="spell"/>


   <!-- A set of fields to contain text extracted from HTML tag contents which we
        can boost at query time. -->
   <dynamicField name="tags_*" type="text"   indexed="true" stored="false" omitNorms="true"/>

   <!-- For 2 and 3 letter prefix dynamic fields, the 1st letter indicates the data type and
        the last letter is 's' for single valued, 'm' for multi-valued -->

   <!-- We use long for integer since 64 bit ints are now common in PHP. -->
   <dynamicField name="is_*"  type="long"    indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
   <dynamicField name="im_*"  type="long"    indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="iss_*" type="slong"   indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
   <dynamicField name="ism_*" type="slong"   indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="ss_*"  type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
   <dynamicField name="sm_*"  type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <!-- Normal text fields are for full text - the relevance of a match depends on the length of the text -->
   <dynamicField name="ts_*"  type="text"    indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" termVectors="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="tm_*"  type="text"    indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true" termVectors="true"/>
   <!-- Unstemmed text fields for full text - the relevance of a match depends on the length of the text -->
   <dynamicField name="tus_*" type="text_und" indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" termVectors="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="tum_*" type="text_und" indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true" termVectors="true"/>
   <!-- These text fields omit norms - useful for extracted text like taxonomy_names -->
   <dynamicField name="tos_*" type="text"    indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" termVectors="true" omitNorms="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="tom_*" type="text"    indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true" termVectors="true" omitNorms="true"/>
   <!-- Special-purpose text fields -->
   <dynamicField name="tes_*" type="edge_n2_kw_text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" />
   <dynamicField name="tem_*" type="edge_n2_kw_text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" />
   <dynamicField name="tws_*" type="text_ws" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
   <dynamicField name="twm_*" type="text_ws" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <!-- trie dates are preferred, so give them the 2 letter prefix -->
   <dynamicField name="ds_*"  type="tdate"   indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
   <dynamicField name="dm_*"  type="tdate"   indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="bm_*"  type="boolean" indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="bs_*"  type="boolean" indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
   <dynamicField name="its_*" type="tlong"   indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
   <dynamicField name="itm_*" type="tlong"   indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="fts_*" type="tfloat"  indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
   <dynamicField name="ftm_*" type="tfloat"  indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="pts_*" type="tdouble" indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
   <dynamicField name="ptm_*" type="tdouble" indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <!-- Binary fields can be populated using base64 encoded data. Useful e.g. for embedding
        a small image in a search result using the data URI scheme -->
   <dynamicField name="xs_*"  type="binary"  indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
   <dynamicField name="xm_*"  type="binary"  indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <!-- In rare cases a sfloat rather than tfloat is needed for sortMissingLast -->
   <dynamicField name="fss_*" type="sfloat"  indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
   <dynamicField name="fsm_*" type="sfloat"  indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="pss_*" type="sdouble" indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
   <dynamicField name="psm_*" type="sdouble" indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <!-- In rare cases a date rather than tdate is needed for sortMissingLast -->
   <dynamicField name="dds_*" type="date"    indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
   <dynamicField name="ddm_*" type="date"    indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <!-- In case a 32 bit int is really needed, we provide these fields. 'h' is mnemonic for 'half word', i.e. 32 bit on 64 arch -->
   <dynamicField name="hs_*" type="integer" indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
   <dynamicField name="hm_*" type="integer" indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="hss_*" type="sint"   indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
   <dynamicField name="hsm_*" type="sint"   indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="hts_*" type="tint"   indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
   <dynamicField name="htm_*" type="tint"   indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

   <!-- Begin added fields to use features in Solr 3.4+ -->
   <dynamicField name="points_*" type="point" indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
   <dynamicField name="pointm_*" type="point" indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="locs_*" type="location" indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
   <dynamicField name="locm_*" type="location" indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="geos_*" type="geohash" indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
   <dynamicField name="geom_*" type="geohash" indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <!-- End added fields for Solr 3.4+ -->
   <!-- Sortable version of the dynamic string field -->
   <dynamicField name="sort_*" type="sortString" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
   <copyField source="ss_*" dest="sort_*"/>
  <!-- A random sort field -->
   <dynamicField name="random_*" type="rand" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <!-- This field is used to store access information (e.g. node access grants), as opposed to field data -->
   <dynamicField name="access_*" type="integer" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>


   <!-- The following causes solr to ignore any fields that don't already match an existing
        field name or dynamic field, rather than reporting them as an error.
        Alternately, change the type="ignored" to some other type e.g. "text" if you want
        unknown fields indexed and/or stored by default -->
   <dynamicField name="*" type="ignored" multiValued="true" />

 </fields>

 <!-- Field to use to determine and enforce document uniqueness.
      Unless this field is marked with required="false", it will be a required field
   -->
 <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>

 <!-- field for the QueryParser to use when an explicit fieldname is absent -->
 <defaultSearchField>content</defaultSearchField>

 <!-- SolrQueryParser configuration: defaultOperator="AND|OR" -->
 <solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND"/>

</schema>
```

I have both a uniquekey (id) and a defaultSearchField.

My output:

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">8</int>
</lst>
<lst name="initArgs">
<lst name="defaults">
<str name="config">dataconfig.xml</str>
</lst>
</lst>
<str name="command">full-import</str>
<str name="status">idle</str>
<str name="importResponse"/>
<lst name="statusMessages">
<str name="Total Requests made to DataSource">1</str>
<str name="Total Rows Fetched">3</str>
<str name="Total Documents Skipped">0</str>
<str name="Full Dump Started">2013-11-14 14:24:04</str>
<str name="Total Documents Processed">0</str>
<str name="Total Documents Failed">3</str>
<str name="Time taken ">0:0:0.45</str>
</lst>
<str name="WARNING">
This response format is experimental. It is likely to change in the future.
</str>
</response>
```

I already tried a lot of different things and nothing worked.. Please help me!

Comment: Are there errors in your Solr log?

Comment: No, there are no errors in the logs...

Comment: what commands are you using for indexing data and checking the status?

Comment: It looks like you have to play with your schema.xml file. can you please put some more detail of your schema.xml file. As I guess that's because you have id field twice or may be your fields doesn't match. Please try to keep only 1 id field and check all your other fields.

Comment: To check the status, I use the following command: 
"....:8983/solr/dataimport"

And for indexing data:
"....:8983/solr/dataimport?command=full-import&clean=false"

Comment: Above I replaced my full schema.xml...

Comment: you need to change your fields in schema.xml according to you data-config.xml.

Comment: I have reviewed your schema.xml file and it looks good to me. Did you define all your fields of schema.xml files to data-config.xml file?

Comment: @anandkhatri:schema.xml has many fields which are not being used in data-config, i think he needs to remove those unwanted fields and keep the once which he actually needs

Comment: @prernaKeshari: yes that may be the cause but it's really a trial and error thing without having error log details.

Comment: The problem is I cannot remove the other fields because I need them for my Drupal index.. The data-config is just additional to my current index.

Answer (score 2):

Please check the required fields in your schema.xml
because Solr do not process a document which is missing a required fieald.(that's why you get rows fetched = # but total documents processed = 0 )

So your mistake here is that you're defining two required fields (id, entity_type) like below:

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" **required="true"** />
<field name="entity_type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" **required="true"** />
```

and here in your entity you're just using the 'id' field, but 'entity_type' wasn't used:

```
 <entity pk="id" query="SELECT `id`,`test_name` FROM `test`">
    <field column="id" name="id" />
    <field column="test_name" name="test_name" />
    <!-- the other required field (entity_type) is missing here -->
 </entity>
```

so either you index this field 'entity_type' in your entity,

or in your case you should remove the required option from its definition in the schema.xml

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the required fields.
required fields should always been used/assigned.

Comment: Required fields should always... what?

Comment: I just wanted to help, and i can not comment yet.

Answer (score 0):

In schema.xml under the field tag, you need to keep only those fields which are present in your data-config.

```
<fields>
   <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
   <field name="test_name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
</fields>
```

And to keep it simple, try to modify part of your data-config like this

```
 <document>
     <entity pk="id" query="SELECT `id`,`test_name` FROM `test`">
        <field column="id" name="id" />
        <field column="test_name" name="test_name" />
     </entity>
  </document>
```

Comment: When I clean my schema.xml and remove all the other fields that are not in my data-config, it seems to work... But then I have another big problem with the rest of the index. Because then, all the other fields I need for my Drupal index cannot be filled (I use the Drupal module for Apache Solr to index my content). Is there any possibility to combine the two index functionalities?

Comment: Sorry, no idea about Drupal.

Comment: Now I've splitted my indexes in two cores. But I don't know how to combine the two in Drupal so that I can search both. Is there anyone who knows about this in Drupal?